# How can I send a POST request without sending an auto incrementing primary key in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am writing a simple API which I have been testing using Postman. I have an auto incrementing primary key (CustomerTypeID) for my "customer_type" table stored in MySQL. For practical reasons I need to be able to create records in this table without sending a CustomerTypeID. When I send the following POST request using Postman:

```
{
  "CustomerType": "testing"
}
```

The updated table shows a new row with CustomerTypeID of 2 and a CustomerType of NULL.

Below is a snippet of code in my Express API which shows this specific query and how the routing for this POST request works.

```
var db = require('../dbconnection.js');
var CustomerType = {
  addCustomerType:function(CustomerType,callback) {
    return db.query("INSERT INTO customer_type (CustomerType) VALUES (?)", [CustomerType.CustomerType], callback);
  }
};
module.exports = CustomerType;
```

I know that I could change the query to say

```
INSERT INTO customer_type (CustomerTypeID, CustomerType) VALUES (?,?);
```

and that would fill both columns. But, I do not know how to leave out the CustomerTypeID column as it will be a number that the end user will have no way of knowing.

Comment: If I understand right, your ID is already correctly inserted - the trouble is with customerType not inserted - so you should check what customerType value is present at time of insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the syntax for the last query I gave is correct. I used the same POST request as before:

```
{
  "CustomerType": "testing"
}
```

And  by using the SQL query that includes CustomerTypeID, MySQL knew to just increment the value of CustomerTypeID since it was not given a value in the POST request. When I ran the same POST again with this query I received a new row with both a CustomerTypeID and a CustomerType.